# How do you maintain proper resource leveling in MS Project after baseline since resource leveling shifts to maintain slack+leveling days?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

Once you have created your schedule with all the known dependencies, leveled resource assignments, and proper baseline, how do you go about maintaining the leveling?

Task A is a driver to task B. Task B has a 5 day leveling delay. Both tasks have different resources with no other assignments. If Task A takes 5 days instead of 1, why does it push out Task B since its a resource leveling delay, not a task leveling delay? This makes it much more difficult to maintain a schedule when you have to constantly adjust your leveling regardless if there is slack or not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your implied distinction between a "task leveling delay" and a "resource leveling delay" is incorrect.  In MSP, any "leveling delay" is a resource leveling delay.  It is applied to a task, an assignment contained by the task, or a part of either, and it's sole purpose is to delay less important work in favor of more important work when resources are limited.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is possible to manually enter leveling delays (as you appear to have done), your purpose is better served by managing leveling delays using the built-in resource leveler.  Here's a re-creation of your example, using the leveler in manual mode (as I always do.)  [image]The initial 5ed leveling delay is necessary to relieve the over-allocation of Mr. B.  The subsequent extension of Task A means the leveling delay is no longer necessary, so the leveler removes it.

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks appear to have a finish-start dependency plus five day lag between A and B.  If you level your resources and that causes A's duration to go from 1 day to 5 days, the FS constraint you establish will push out B to start when A finishes including the five day lag.  The constraint you established suggests that B must wait for A to finish, either because of task logic or resources, and that there "has" to be five days in between the two tasks.  In your predecessor column, did you write FS+5days?  If so, then it is not "slack" but rather a hard coded lag.  If it was true slack, then the extended duration of A will not move out B; it'll consume the slack.

So check what you have in the predecessor column as your dependency.

Comment: Task B has a 5ed leveling delay, not a lag.  Leveling delays are normally applied, adjusted, and otherwise managed by the resource leveling engine, but it appears here that the OP has entered it directly.  Once entered, of course, the leveling delay looks a lot like a lag (on the forward pass.)

Comment: @TomBoyle, the five days between A and B was due to the leveling delay?  I avoid using the auto leveling function.  Will you provide an answer as to what is occurring here?